# Is it possible to instantiate an array of variable lengths with indices of all -1 in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to create an integer array i with a variable length k, where all indices are some specified value, say -1?

I know I *could* do something like:

```
int[] i = new int[k];
for (int a = 0; a < k; a++) {
     i[a] = -1;
}
```

Are there any short-cuts that would not require the for-loop?

Comment: You mean all *elements* are -1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Arrays.fill` is the shortcut you are looking for:

```
int[] arr = new int[100];
Arrays.fill(arr, -1);
```

docs are somewhere in here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: the simplest answers at 1AM get the most rep :P

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn't any shortcut for that. The default value is 0 and you cannot overwrite it.